How to search for a exact phrase match in files with certain extension - Your query couldn't be parsed. We've searched with a modified query
In bitbucket this search query
project:Foo repo:bar "my current status"  (ext:xml OR ext:html)  archived:true

returns some matches but also returns

Your query couldn't be parsed. We've searched with a modified query.

Changing it to
project:Foo repo:bar ("my current status") AND (ext:xml OR ext:html)  AND (archived:true)
project:Foo AND repo:bar AND ("my current status") AND (ext:xml OR ext:html)  AND (archived:true)

returned the same warning Your query couldn't be parsed. We ...
My understanding of the docs about search is that the query above should be valid.
How can bitbucket be searched for

files that contain an exact phrase (for example: my current status or My Current Status - so upper or lower case should both match)
only files with an file extension of xml or html
only where archived == true

